# Java array initialization guarantees

Tags: java, arrays, initialization

Does Java guarantee array initialization?

Let's say I use the code `char[] uuid = new char[36];`, would each element be guaranteed to be initialized to 0?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes. [JLS §10.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.3) ensures that all elements of an array are set to their initial values, which by [JLS §4.12.5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.5) is guaranteed to be `0`, `false`, or `null`.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it does guarantee initialization. [JLS section 10.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.3)